# Split string on any number of white spaces in C

Tags: c, file, parsing

I have a file where each username and password is separated by a different number of white spaces.

```
bob    passowrd1
saly password2
sam      password2

void parse()
{
    FILE*open;
    open = fopen("file.txt");
    char line[101];
    char*name;
    char*password;

    while(fgets(100,line,open)!=NULL)
    {
       name = strtok(line,"*\\s");
       password = strtok(NULL,"*\\s");
       printf("username : %s",name);
       printf("password : %s",password); 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to split the string using strtok but it doesn't accept regex as a delimeter. The only other way i can think of doing this is brute forcing by forlooping over the string and creating 2 new seperate strings after the whitespaces. any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: Start with a `for` loop and a `switch` statement.

Comment: I've got serious concerns about why you're storing **plaintext passwords** though.

Comment: @tadman this is just an intro class, i understand storing password in plaintext isn't safe

Comment: The `scanf` function family ignores all leading whitespace for some formats such as `%s`. `if(fscanf(myfile, "%s%s", name, password) != 2) { /* bad input */ }`

Comment: The last example password containing a space `"password 2"` is awful. Don't buck the system.

Comment: @WeatherVane that was just a typo

Comment: Re my first comment a better solution would be to read each line of the file with `fgets` and then apply `sscanf`. This makes it easy to dump an invalid entry. There are plenty of SO questions and example code here for you to find. You haven't posted any attempt, so the question is off topic.

Comment: "I'm trying to split the string using strtok but it doesn't accept regex as a delimeter." --> post that code.  VTC as no [MCVE] provided.

Comment: Maybe try reading [`man strtok`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html): "a sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter bytes in the parsed string is considered to be a single delimiter, and that delimiter bytes at the start or end of the string are ignored."

Comment: @WeatherVane im just trying to read from a plaintext file.

Comment: Certainly `while(fgets(100,line,open)!=NULL)` is not the true working code.  Please post your true working/compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If available you can use `strsep` (string separate). `strsep` takes a set of separators and will step through a string separating it into fields. It's superior to `strtok` as it does not keep a hidden global state.

```
void split_fields_strsep( char *string ) {
    char *field;
    const char *delimiters = " \t\n";

    while( (field = strsep(&string, delimiters)) != NULL ) {
        // Multiple spaces will show up as multiple empty fields.
        // Skip them.
        if( *field == '\0' ) {
            continue;
        }

        printf("field: '%s'\n", field);
    }
}
```

Note that each `field` is a pointer into the original `string`. `strsep` will split the string into fields by placing null bytes at the end of each field. If `string` is `foo bar  baz  \0` you will end with `foo\0bar\0 baz\0 \0`. So be sure to `strdup` the string if you want to preserve it.

---

If `strsep` is not available, the standard `strtok` will work. It works similarly to `strsep` and will alter the original string by adding null bytes.

```
void split_fields_strtok( char *string ) {
    const char *delimiters = " \t\n";

    for(
        char *field = strtok(string, delimiters);
        field != NULL;
        field = strtok(NULL, delimiters)
    ) {
        printf("field: '%s'\n", field);
    }
}
```

Comment: `strsep` does exactly what OP *doesn't* want: it considers each individual delimiter character to be an individual delimiter. ("One difference between strsep and strtok_r is that if the input string contains more than one byte from delimiter in a row strsep returns an empty string for each pair of bytes from delimiter. " Quote is from glibc's info file.). `strtok` does the right thing but its interface is awful. If possible, use [`strtok_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html)

Comment: @rici I accounted for `strsep`'s behavior in the code, there's a comment and everything. I agree about `strtok`, but I wanted to offer a standard option as many classes stick to C90. `strtok_r` is at least POSIX standard, so there's that, but I find `strsep` easier to use and more flexible when pulling apart separated fields where you often want to preserve empty fields, though not in this particular case.

Comment: Between a non-standard extension and a Posix standard function, I'd personally go with the latter, and particularly if it Does The Right Thing. Of course, you might have a libc which implements the Appendix K `strtok_s` interface. It's true that `strsep` is pretty common, but these days so is `strtok_r`. And apologies for not reading your code.

Comment: @rici You should have seen [what I'd written before](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50310647/1). ;)

Answer (score 6):

You (and most of the respondents) are overthinking this.  strtok() delimits on one or more of the delimiters, so

```
name = strtok(line," ");
password = strtok(NULL," ");
```

will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Using `fgets()` to fill `line[]`, this quick answer will included `'\n'` in `password` as tokenizing on only the `" "` is not sufficient nor exact to meet OP's  "creating 2 new separate strings after the _white-spaces_"

Answer (score 0):

> Split string on any number of white spaces in C

`"*\\s"` indicates a misunderstanding of how to code token characters.  `"*\\s"` looks for 3 characters `*`, `\` and `s` as tokens, none of those indicate white-spaces when used with `strtok()`.

---

Parse the input line for white-space with an explicit list.  Be sure to account for the trailing `'\n'` of the line of input or other *white-space*.

*White space* in C includes a number  of characters:

> The standard white-space characters are the following: space (`' '`), form feed (`'\f'`), new-line (`'\n'`), carriage return (`'\r'`), horizontal tab (`'\t'`), and vertical tab (`'\v'`).
>   C11dr §7.4.1.10 2

```
// while(fgets(100,line,open)!=NULL)
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, open)) {  // Destination array is first argument

  const char *standard_white_space = " \f\n\r\t\v";
  name = strtok(line, standard_white_space);
  password = strtok(NULL, standard_white_space);
  printf("username : <%s>\n",name);
  printf("password : <%s>\n",password); 

}
```

---

Alternatively, use `isspace()` or a `" "` in a `sscanf()`.

---

Tip: to insure code did not include white-space in `username, password`, print the string with sentinel characters like `<>` to more easily detect coding errors.

```
  char line[] = "bob    passowrd1\n";
  char*name = strtok(line, " ");
  char* password = strtok(NULL, " ");
  printf("username : <%s>\n", name);
  printf("password : <%s>\n", password);
```

This outputs

```
username : <bob>
password : <passowrd1    <-- Oops
>
```