# POSIX Regex parsing command line and getting arguments

Tags: regex, posix

I'm trying to parse a command line using regex and use the output to get each argument. (Forgot to mention, i don't know how many argument i'll have)

In order to simplify my C code, i would need to have one command line corresponding to one match

Here is my regex

```
^([[:graph:]]+)[[:blank:]]{0,}
```

And here are my test lines :

```
command
/command

command argument
/command argument

command argument
/command    arrgument

command argument1 argument2
/command argument1 argument2

command argument1   argument2
/command    argument1   argument2
```

(i didn't yet think about non-match exemples)

This is the output i'm trying to have

```
Match1
Full String : command
Group1 : command

Match2
Full String : /command
Group1 : /command

Match3
Full String : command argument
Group1 : command
Group2 : argument

Match4
Full String : /command argument
Group1 : /command
Group2 : argument

Match5
Full String : command   argument
Group1 : command
Group2 : argument

Match6
Full String : /command  argument
Group1 : /command
Group2 : argument

Match7
Full String : command argument1 argument2
Group1 : command
Group2 : argument1
Group3 : argument2

Match8
Full String : /command argument1 argument2
Group1 : /command
Group2 : argument1
Group3 : argument2

Match9
Full String : command   argument1   argument2
Group1 : command
Group2 : argument1
Group3 : argument2

Match10
Full String : /command  argument1   argument2
Group1 : /command
Group2 : argument1
Group3 : argument2
```

I use `global`, `multi line` and `extended`

https://regex101.com/r/x6H5WC/3/

Comment: You are coding it in C, using `regex.h`?

Comment: Yep @WiktorStribiżew
Didn't think this information was useful because i'm mainly asking for help on the regex not on the code itself :)

Comment: Ok, then please bear in mind that the number of capturing groups is static and is set by the pattern. If you have one pair of parentheses, you will have 1 capturing group - and no more. Probably, you should think of an approach other than a regex, or at least other than a single regex.

Comment: Okay then there is no possible way to tell my regex, that between start and end of a line i want to capture  all groups that looks like ```[[:graph:]]+``` ?

Comment: No, you can't. At least with  1 regex method call.

Comment: Kay, Thanks for the help, i'll use multiple match then :)

Comment: Check [Split string on any number of white spaces in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310178/split-string-on-any-number-of-white-spaces-in-c)